# TokuDB table stats row count decreases very fast while adding/updateing data

Tags: percona, percona-server, tokudb

We run an Percona server with the newest version(5.7.19-17). 
After a while the cardinality of multiple tables drop to zero.
A new created index also have an cardinality of 0 if the existing are zero.
I can repair this by do

```
set session tokudb_analyze_mode = TOKUDB_ANALYZE_RECOUNT_ROWS;
ANALYZE table myTable;
```

or

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name` ENGINE=TokuDB;
```

After some tests I found the row count droping over time.
As far as I understand the, this influences also the cardinality. 
The table contains around 800.000 entries and is written nearly the whole day.

```
CREATE TABLE `table_name` (
`val1` char(2) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
`val2` char(15) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
`val3` char(15) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
`val4` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`val1`,`val2`),
KEY `reverse_key` (`val1`,`val3`)
) ENGINE=TokuDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin ROW_FORMAT=TOKUDB_LZMA;
```

Mostly I write with `REPLACE INTO` and `INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` into this table and update nearly 100% of the data per day. Both insert methods are tested with the same behavior.

I start an simple script which just print the calculated row count over time

```
SELECT TABLE_ROWS FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'shema_name' AND TABLE_NAME = 'table_name';
```

[image]

You can see the row count is decreasing very fast.

Can anyone explain to me where this behavior comes from and I can handle it?

Comment: 3%/hour does not seem like much, especially considering that `TABLE_ROWS` can be as much as a factor of two off.

Comment: Did you really want `REPLACE` -- which does `DELETE` + `INSERT`?  Consider IODKU.

Comment: @RickJames I just attached a longer log. I see your point. 3% per houre is not that mutch but it leads to full table scans after 2 days because the row count  and so also the cardinality of all indexes for this table is zero. This could not be the normal behavior. Did I missunderstod something here?

Comment: @RickJames checked to change REPLACE to IODKU but it shows the same behavior. Table is down to 600k now.

Comment: Do `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tablename` to see how many rows there _really_ are.  It is the correct value, and likely to be different than any of the values you get the query we are discussing.

Comment: @RickJames Thats where i get the 800k rows from. It is currently 892k rows. Row count in the statistics gives me 580k now.

Comment: I just checked one of my tables:  `STATUS` says `Rows: 26567`; `COUNT(*)` says `46921`.  So, I am not surprised by 892K vs 580K.  Different engines compute the `STATUS` row count different.  `MyISAM` is always exact; others are estimate - but they are fast.

Comment: The origin source of this inspection is, that some of our tables drop once a day to 0 rows/cardinality (not at a specific time but under load) and did not serve the live traffic anymore because a heavy load of full table scans. The current table with its slowly droping numbers is a 1:1 copy of the broken table.

Comment: The "0" I do not have an explanation for.  What happens after you do `ANALYZE TABLE` ?

Comment: if I do
`TOKUDB_ANALYZE_RECOUNT_ROWS`
it recount the rows mostly after some tries
 `TOKUDB_ANALYZE_STANDARD`
change nothing

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem? I faced the same issue. This was reported as a TokuDB bug - https://jira.percona.com/browse/PS-4293